# Unable to open .php files on linux browser

Tags: php

I've transfer some of my .php files from windows to linux(ubuntu),  eg:admin.php
however i can't open the .php file when i double click the file which is inside my /var/www/eugene folder. 
When i key in locahhost/eugene, nothing pops out or it'll pops out 404 error when clearly there's codes in my files.
Can someone please notify me or guide me through it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have apache/php running?  And when you say you double click the file, are you expecting to open the file in a code editor, or browser?

Comment: A few things to confirm: a) Are you sure there's an http server running on your machine? b) Can the http server can handle PHP? and c) Are you sure that it's serving files from /var/www/?

Comment: Yes my apache2/php5 is running, i'm expecting to view it on browser, not text editor.

Comment: I'm quite new to php and linux. Just to clarify do i have to type in localhost/eugene/admin.php in the browser to view my files(not working), or could i just double click on my .php files which immediate pops out the web browser(what i want), it stats my .php was not found on this server. \

Comment: It might be a bug, because when i open it form /localhost.../, nothings appear. I doubt it's error because i've already permit it and there are php codes in my files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a) Are you sure there's an http server running on your machine? b) Can the http server can handle PHP? and c) Are you sure that it's serving files from /var/www/? as pointed by [stvcisco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470414/stvcisco)

And if you still have got the problem you can try following, because these type issue sometimes occur due to absence of read permission in the directory and files :

```
chmod -R o+r /var/www/eugene
```

Also you may need

```
chmod -R o+x /var/www/eugene
```